# Error number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1) in R

Tags: r, rbind

I've got the upper error message error when trying to execute the following code

`` Nome_Dos_Formadores <- rbind(V_Nome_Dos_Formadores$`Nome do Formador`, N_Nome_Dos_Formadores$`Nome do Formador`) ``

Can you help me solving this error?

Comment: Not enough information. We would need to see results of `str` on those dataframes to know. Why are you giving only vectors to `rbind`. Generally people would give either matrices or dataframes. Perhaps you actually want: `Nome_Dos_Formadores <- rbind(V_Nome_Dos_Formadores, N_Nome_Dos_Formadores)`

Comment: @IRTFM this is the right solution. Can you answer with this text and then I can accept is as a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see results of str on those dataframes to know for sure. You code was only giving vectors to rbind. Generally people would want to use `rbind` for either matrices or dataframes. Perhaps you actually want:

```
Nome_Dos_Formadores <- rbind(V_Nome_Dos_Formadores, N_Nome_Dos_Formadores)
```